# Adding a vector of numbers from MATLAB to a list in C#

Tags: c#, events, list, matlab

Could anyone suggest a straightforward way to take a vector of numbers from MATLAB and add those numbers to a list in C# to be called upon by an event in the C# program? I've found a lot of information on the interface between the two languages, but I'm very new to c# and could use the specificity. Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call MATLAB from a C# program, use the NE Builder toolbox.  There are lots of examples of how it works [here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/dotnetbuilder/ug/exampleindex.html).

Your MATLAB code will look something like

```
function y = GenerateSomeNumbers()
   y = rand(1, 10);
end
```

Build this into `MyMatlabComponent.dll` with the builder, and add a reference to this dll in your C# program.

Your C# code will look something like

```
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
using MyMatlabComponent;

// ...

// Inside the appropriate method
List<double> l = new List<double>();
MyMatlabComponentclass c = new MyMatlabComponentclass();
MWNumericArray m = c.GenerateSomeNumbers();
l.Add((double)m);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods.

First, you can use COM as a bridge. see

http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/153172

http://topic.csdn.net/u/20090402/16/6db37a24-648c-4f8d-a353-42eab4c4bcbe.html

http://www.sciencenet.cn/m/user_content.aspx?id=304113

Second, you can use matlab-net-API. see

http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/f16-35614.html#brxerx8-1

and

http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/exampleindex.html